# Экземпляры класса

Tags: c#, vb.net

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы все экземпляры класса "Note" использовали один и тот же midiOut ? То есть чтобы он (midiOut) не создавался для каждого экземпляра.

```
Class Note
    Public midiOut As Midi.MidiOut = New Midi.MidiOut(0)

    Public Sub Play()
        midiOut.Send(Midi.MidiMessage.StartNote(note, 127, 1).RawData)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        midiOut.Send(Midi.MidiMessage.StopNote(note, 0, 1).RawData)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Попробовал объявить midiOut как Shared - помогло , но правильно ли я поступил ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`Shared`](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/sharedinstance.htm) в `VB` имеет семантику `static`, а значит относится к классу вообще, а не к какому-то конкретному объекту класса.
- `midiOut` в этом примере правильнее объявлять как `Private Shared`, либо использовать примерно следующий паттерн:

[image: http://yuml.me/e0d4634f]